# Mapping an array into a dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to map some data into a dropdown menu, however, when expanded it doesn't show any data. But mapping the data into the console works.

Could it be a problem that the data is retrieved from database on componentDidMount? I've noticed that as the page is loading the array is first loged into the console as empty, and the next second it has the data in it. Does anyone have any suggestions on how to fix this?

The mapping in the dropdown button:

```
<div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
    {console.log(this.state.devicenames)}
  {this.state.devicenames.map((number) => ( 
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#" >{number}</a>
                        ))}
  </div>
```

Getting data from database on componentDidMout:

```
componentDidMount() {
    const uid = this.state.user.uid;
        const serialRef = db.ref(uid + '/serials');
        serialRef.on('value', (serial_numbers) => {
          const serials = [];
          const devicename = [];
          serial_numbers.forEach((serial_number) => {
            const za = serial_number.val();
            const ta = za.serial;
            const nameRef = db.ref(ta + '/devicename');
        nameRef.on('value', (dname)=> {
          devicename.push(dname.val());
        })
      })
      this.setState({devicenames: devicename})
    })
}
```

[image: A screenshot of the array]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Looks like something in the render , might be css or a missing return , hard to see w/o the full code. Try to render some static element just to see if you got the render right.

Comment: @Eran the static method works fine. I've just noticed that it works correctly if I open the page with the dropdown menu from another page, however, the dropdown doesn't show the mapped data if I refresh the page. Then the dropdown is emtpy again.

Comment: Can you log: this.state.devicenames.length ?

Comment: And also 
{this.state.devicenames.map((number) => { 
                        console.log('number=',number)
                        return <a class="dropdown-item" href="#" >{number}</a>
                        )}}